# VBA - How to loop through 2 Columns and then extract data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in Column H and I, for example:

```
   H        I
**Name 1   Name 2**        
 Johnny   
          Anderson
          Sophie
 Howie
```

I would like to loop through these 2 Columns of data, extract the last 3 letters on the right and finally display them in Column J, here is what I came up with:

```
Sub Extract_info()

    Dim cell As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cell In .Range("H2:I", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
            If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
                Range("J2").Value = Right(cell.Value, 3)
            End If
        
        Next cell
    End With

End Sub
```

The above doesn't seem to work. May I know how should I get this worked?

Comment: Replace `ActiveCell` with `cell` then it should work.

Comment: Notice you are looping trough 2 columns (H, I) but your final output is J. In case there is any row with values at both columns H and I one of the outputs will be overwritten.

Comment: `.Range("H2:I" &  .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close, but you have several issues:

- Finding the row count in column A isn't robust when your data are in columns H:I
- Setting `Range("J2").Value` will put every result in J2, not in the specific target row. Make it dynamic
- @Ike is right, the `ActiveCell` doesn't change throughout your loop; you need to refer to `cell`

This is one alternative that works. Note that this implies that each row has at most one entry in columns `H:I`. If both columns have an entry the second will overwrite the first. But that's the case for the way you've described your data too.

```
Sub Extract_info()
    Dim cell As Range, rngSource As Range
    
    Set rngSource = ActiveSheet.Range("H2:I" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    
    For Each cell In rngSource
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            Range("J" & cell.Row).Value = Right(cell.Value, 3)
        End If
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

And when you post the next question, "doesn't seem to work" doesn't explain the problem. In this case it was obvious, but usually we need more than that to understand what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I will remember on how to structure the expected outcome properly next time. Meanwhile, just 1 question from me, is there a difference to use `IsEmpty(cell.Value)` and `IsEmpty(cell)`?

Comment: No difference. The default member of a range object is .Value, so both are the same. But it never hurts to be explicit, so including the .Value makes it clear.